# Python understanding regex

Tags: python, regex

Hi I'm reading some code and found `re.compile("<@(U\S+)>")`, I'm having some trouble to understand the `<>`. Can someone give an example that matches? I have tried in python interactive shell with `'<@U>'` or `'<@jyx>'` and they do not match. Thanks.

Comment: `\S+` means more than one none space character and it should come after `<@U` and before `>` like `<@Ua>` ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<>` have no significance as such.

You have to provide `<@U` then `1 or more non space characters` then `>` to match.

Like

```
<@UASD>
<@US>
```

Your input

```
<@U> did not match as no non space character present after U

<@asd> did not match as no U present after @
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't need a literal `S` to match this regex (your current examples both have an `S`, which could confuse someone). `<@Under>` is another example that will match this pattern.